# com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I'm new to android development. I developed the app through Android Studio, using firebase as the backend, and ran everything through emulator. When I'm trying to build an application using G translate API. I have enabled every authentication in GCP console. error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{testing.com.login/testing.com.login.MainActivity}: com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: The request is missing a valid API key.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: The request is missing a valid API key.
    at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$4.call(TranslateImpl.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$4.call(TranslateImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.translate(TranslateImpl.java:124)
    at testing.com.login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.translate.spi.v2.HttpTranslateRpc.translate(HttpTranslateRpc.java:130)
        ... 21 more
```

I have added the environment variables (GOOGLE_API_KEY,GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) in my Windows based computer. However when I debug the code using System.getProperties() function, it returned value like SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH,ANDROID_STORAGE,PATH,ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote,etc instead of my computer's variables. Where these variables comes from?

Answer (score -1):

Environment variables like **SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH** and **ANDROID_STORAGE** are environment variables set up at init time by the Android system,

for example, with the **init.environ.rc.in** init file. If you have set up a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Service Account with the permissions you need, then you will need to include both the credential file and export the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** variable pointing to that file as per this document on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable , on that init file for Android.

Note both the credential file and the path to that credential file will be on and be accessible from the Android system.